# Comparing and finding an ArrayList with the longest length

Tags: java, arraylist

I am solving a task linked to the Collatz Problem. I have created a method that produces 1 from any starting number:

```
    public static void sequence(int value)
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> calc = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        calc.add(value);

while(value != 1)
    {

            if(value % 2 == 0)
            {
                value = value / 2;
            }

            else if(value % 2 != 0)
            {
                value = (value * 3) + 1;
            }

            calc.add(value);

            if(value == 1 )
            {
                    System.out.println(calc);
                }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int x = 1000000; x > 0; x--)
        {
        sequence(x);
        }
    }

}
```

The next part of my task is finding a method which will find the longest Collatz sequence below 1,000,000.

I came up with several solutions such as the one below..of course none of them worked.

```
while(value != 1)
        {

            if(value % 2 == 0)
            {
                value = value / 2;
            }

            else if(value % 2 != 0)
            {
                value = (value * 3) + 1;
            }

            calc1.add(value);

            if(calc1.size() > calc2.size())
            {
                calc2 = calc1;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(calc2);
    }
```

Could anyone please help and guide me to finding the correct methods for finding the longest Collatz sequence using the comparison of 2 or more ArrayLists. If there are better options than the use of an ArrayList I more than welcome these methods. 
Thanks.

Comment: It is confusing to have a method `calc` and a variable `calc` (in addition, the name `calc` is not the best).

Comment: @C-Otto Thanks for pointing out the duplication, I did not realise. And as for the name calc for the ArrayList, what is the issue with this?

Comment: First, it is an abbreviation for `calculation` or `calculated`. There's no need to be short, so don't abbreviate. Then, this name does not tell _what_ is calculated. I think names like `calculateCollatz` or `computeCollatzList` or `collatzSequence` may be better names, than convey a meaning and help others understand the code.

Comment: @C-Otto I used the abbreviation of calculation because I knew what it meant to me personally, however, I did not create the code knowing I would be showing it to others to understand. Having said that, I see your point and will make sure I edit code next time I ask a question for others to understand.

Comment: Always write so that even any inexperienced and overtired developer can read your code and immediately understands what is happening - sometimes you're even helping yourself if you try to understand your own code a few days/weeks/years after you wrote it.

Comment: @C-Otto Thanks for the advice, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain a maxList which will get updated with the longest sequence.

You can either pass it to your `calc()` method in each call or declare it as a Class variable for using it on top of both `calc()` and `main()` methods.

```
// to update the max list
maxList = (list.size() > maxList.size()) ? list : maxList;
```

At the end just print the results

```
System.out.println(maxList.size());
System.out.println(maxList);
```

---

Update: You need to figure out efficient ways to pass numbers in the `calc()` method.
It will throw `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` for large input.

Comment: In your code, you have used the value of '100000' for the loop. At this value, the solution produced an output. However, when I changed it to the required 1,000,000 it no longer worked?